# Ant replace task using replacefilterfile only on certain lines

Tags: regex, ant, build, build-process

I need to process and replace values on my files based on match/replace lines defined into a property file.

```
<replace dir="${build.dir}" replacefilterfile="replmap.properties">
        <include name="**/*.js"/>
        <include name="**/*.html"/>
</replace>
```

The problem is that I want to limit these replaces to be applied only to lines that don't contain certain string value (before or after the match).

I read documentation about `replaceregexp` searching an alternative solution, but I can't see a way to take de matches/replaces from a properties file.

Comment: The [LineContains and ReplaceTokens filters](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/filterchain.html) could be useful.

Comment: It's correct. Usign filters could be solved the problem, but sadly the `Replace` or `ReplaceRegExp` tasks does not allow `FilterChain` as nested parameter.

Comment: You can substitute `<replace>` with either a `<copy>` or `<move>` and a `<filterchain>` nested within it.